# Cannot POST nodejs form

Tags: html, node.js, express

**edit 2**

So I have tried

```
router.get('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  CompetitionForm.find(req.params.id, function(err, CompetitionForm){
    res.render('dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Competition Form',
      user_id: req.params.id
    });
  });
});
```

As mentioned by @YouneL I have also edited my post route to the following

```
// competition form edit
router.post('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', (req, res) => {
  var schoolName = req.body.schoolName;
  var competitionDate = req.body.competitionDate;
  var competitionTime = req.body.competitionTime;
  var competitionVenue = req.body.competitionVenue;
  var competitionTotalOfStudents = req.body.competitionTotalOfStudents;
  var competitionTotalParticipated = req.body.competitionTotalParticipated;
  var competitionTotalPersonnel = req.body.competitionTotalPersonnel;
  var competitionJudge1Name = req.body.competitionJudge1Name;
  var competitionJudge1Telephone = req.body.competitionJudge1Telephone;
  var competitionJudge1Email = req.body.competitionJudge1Email;
  var competitionJudge2Name = req.body.competitionJudge2Name;
  var competitionJudge2Telephone = req.body.competitionJudge2Telephone;
  var competitionJudge2Email = req.body.competitionJudge2Email;
  var competitionJudge3Name = req.body.competitionJudge3Name;
  var competitionJudge3Telephone = req.body.competitionJudge3Telephone;
  var competitionJudge3Email = req.body.competitionJudge3Email;

  // admin fields
  var competitionRequiredPhotos = req.body.competitionRequiredPhotos;
  var competitionRequiredCertifications = req.body.competitionRequiredCertification;

  console.log(CompetitionForm);
  console.log('form successful');
  res.redirect('/dashboard');
});
```

So now when the form is submitted I get redirected to the dashboard however there are no updates to the database there should be a new collection for the competition form called CompetitionForm

[image]

**edit 1**

I ran `console.log(CompetitionForm);` on the post route and I get the following output.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js hbs, css`
Server is up on port 3000
Connection has been established
Connection has been established
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:21 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/5a5c6740b9e210087e098fd6
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:21 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /users/login
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:22 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /favicon.ico
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:29 GMT+0000 (GMT): POST /users/login
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:29 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /users/login
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:29 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /favicon.ico
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:34 GMT+0000 (GMT): POST /users/login
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:34 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /dashboard
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:34 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /favicon.ico
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:36 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/5a5c6740b9e210087e098fd6
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:15:37 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /favicon.ico
Fri Jan 19 2018 17:16:07 GMT+0000 (GMT): POST /dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/5a5c6740b9e210087e098fd6
{ [Function: model]
  hooks: Kareem { _pres: {}, _posts: {} },
  base: 
   Mongoose {
     connections: [ [NativeConnection] ],
     models: { User: [Function], CompetitionForm: [Circular] },
     modelSchemas: { User: [Schema], CompetitionForm: [Schema] },
     options: { pluralization: true },
     plugins: [ [Array], [Array], [Array] ] },
  modelName: 'CompetitionForm',
  model: [Function: model],
  db: 
   NativeConnection {
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Array],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        plugins: [Array] },
     collections: 
      { users: [NativeCollection],
        competitionforms: [NativeCollection] },
     models: { User: [Function], CompetitionForm: [Circular] },
     config: { autoIndex: true },
     replica: false,
     hosts: null,
     host: 'localhost',
     port: 27017,
     user: null,
     pass: null,
     name: 'pol-development',
     options: null,
     otherDbs: [],
     states: 
      { '0': 'disconnected',
        '1': 'connected',
        '2': 'connecting',
        '3': 'disconnecting',
        '4': 'unauthorized',
        '99': 'uninitialized',
        disconnected: 0,
        connected: 1,
        connecting: 2,
        disconnecting: 3,
        unauthorized: 4,
        uninitialized: 99 },
     _readyState: 1,
     _closeCalled: false,
     _hasOpened: true,
     _listening: false,
     _connectionOptions: {},
     _events: { error: [Array] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     db: 
      Db {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        s: [Object],
        serverConfig: [Getter],
        bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
        databaseName: [Getter] } },
  discriminators: undefined,
  '$appliedMethods': true,
  '$appliedHooks': true,
  _events: { init: [Function], save: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  schema: 
   Schema {
     obj: 
      { schoolName: [Function: String],
        competitionDate: [Function: String],
        competitionTime: [Function: String],
        competitionVenue: [Function: String],
        competitionTotalOfStudents: [Function: Number],
        competitionTotalParticipated: [Function: Number],
        competitionTotalPersonnel: [Function: Number],
        competitionJudge1Name: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge1Telephone: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge1Email: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge2Name: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge2Telephone: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge2Email: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge3Name: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge3Telephone: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge3Email: [Function: String],
        competitionRequiredPhotos: [Function: Boolean],
        competitionRequiredCertifications: [Function: Boolean] },
     paths: 
      { schoolName: [SchemaString],
        competitionDate: [SchemaString],
        competitionTime: [SchemaString],
        competitionVenue: [SchemaString],
        competitionTotalOfStudents: [SchemaNumber],
        competitionTotalParticipated: [SchemaNumber],
        competitionTotalPersonnel: [SchemaNumber],
        competitionJudge1Name: [SchemaString],
        competitionJudge1Telephone: [SchemaString],
        competitionJudge1Email: [SchemaString],
        competitionJudge2Name: [SchemaString],
        competitionJudge2Telephone: [SchemaString],
        competitionJudge2Email: [SchemaString],
        competitionJudge3Name: [SchemaString],
        competitionJudge3Telephone: [SchemaString],
        competitionJudge3Email: [SchemaString],
        competitionRequiredPhotos: [SchemaBoolean],
        competitionRequiredCertifications: [SchemaBoolean],
        _id: [ObjectId],
        __v: [SchemaNumber] },
     aliases: {},
     subpaths: {},
     virtuals: { id: [VirtualType] },
     singleNestedPaths: {},
     nested: {},
     inherits: {},
     callQueue: [ [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ],
     _indexes: [],
     methods: {},
     statics: {},
     tree: 
      { schoolName: [Function: String],
        competitionDate: [Function: String],
        competitionTime: [Function: String],
        competitionVenue: [Function: String],
        competitionTotalOfStudents: [Function: Number],
        competitionTotalParticipated: [Function: Number],
        competitionTotalPersonnel: [Function: Number],
        competitionJudge1Name: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge1Telephone: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge1Email: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge2Name: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge2Telephone: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge2Email: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge3Name: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge3Telephone: [Function: String],
        competitionJudge3Email: [Function: String],
        competitionRequiredPhotos: [Function: Boolean],
        competitionRequiredCertifications: [Function: Boolean],
        _id: [Object],
        __v: [Function: Number],
        id: [VirtualType] },
     query: {},
     childSchemas: [],
     plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     s: { hooks: [Kareem], kareemHooks: [Object] },
     _userProvidedOptions: undefined,
     options: 
      { retainKeyOrder: false,
        typeKey: 'type',
        id: true,
        noVirtualId: false,
        _id: true,
        noId: false,
        validateBeforeSave: true,
        read: null,
        shardKey: null,
        autoIndex: null,
        minimize: true,
        discriminatorKey: '__t',
        versionKey: '__v',
        capped: false,
        bufferCommands: true,
        strict: true,
        pluralization: true },
     '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
  collection: 
   NativeCollection {
     collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
     opts: 
      { bufferCommands: true,
        capped: false,
        '$wasForceClosed': undefined },
     name: 'competitionforms',
     collectionName: 'competitionforms',
     conn: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Mongoose],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        name: 'pol-development',
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: false,
        _connectionOptions: {},
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        db: [Db] },
     queue: [],
     buffer: false,
     emitter: 
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined } },
  Query: 
   { [Function]
     base: 
      Query {
        toConstructor: [Function: toConstructor],
        setOptions: [Function],
        collection: [Function: collection],
        '$where': [Function],
        where: [Function],
        equals: [Function: equals],
        eq: [Function: eq],
        or: [Function: or],
        nor: [Function: nor],
        and: [Function: and],
        gt: [Function],
        gte: [Function],
        lt: [Function],
        lte: [Function],
        ne: [Function],
        in: [Function],
        nin: [Function],
        all: [Function],
        regex: [Function],
        size: [Function],
        maxDistance: [Function],
        minDistance: [Function],
        mod: [Function],
        exists: [Function],
        elemMatch: [Function],
        within: [Function: within],
        box: [Function],
        polygon: [Function],
        circle: [Function],
        near: [Function: near],
        intersects: [Function: intersects],
        geometry: [Function: geometry],
        select: [Function: select],
        slice: [Function],
        sort: [Function],
        limit: [Function],
        skip: [Function],
        maxScan: [Function],
        batchSize: [Function],
        comment: [Function],
        maxTime: [Function],
        snapshot: [Function],
        hint: [Function],
        slaveOk: [Function],
        read: [Function],
        tailable: [Function],
        merge: [Function],
        find: [Function],
        cursor: [Function: cursor],
        findOne: [Function],
        count: [Function],
        distinct: [Function],
        update: [Function: update],
        updateMany: [Function: updateMany],
        updateOne: [Function: updateOne],
        replaceOne: [Function: replaceOne],
        remove: [Function],
        deleteOne: [Function],
        deleteMany: [Function],
        findOneAndUpdate: [Function],
        findOneAndRemove: [Function],
        _findAndModify: [Function],
        _wrapCallback: [Function],
        setTraceFunction: [Function],
        exec: [Function: exec],
        thunk: [Function],
        then: [Function],
        stream: [Function],
        selected: [Function: selected],
        selectedInclusively: [Function: selectedInclusively],
        selectedExclusively: [Function: selectedExclusively],
        _mergeUpdate: [Function],
        _optionsForExec: [Function],
        _fieldsForExec: [Function],
        _updateForExec: [Function],
        _ensurePath: [Function],
        _validate: [Function] } },
  '$__insertMany': [Function],
  insertMany: [Function],
  '$init': Promise { [Circular] } }
```

**Original**

I'm trying to create a nodejs form within a dashboard based off the users id, but it can't post for some reason.

Here is some code:

```
<form action="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{user.id}}" method="post">
```

routes

```
// competition form details
router.get('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  CompetitionForm.find(req.params.id, function(err, CompetitionForm){
    res.render('dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Competition Form',
    });
  });
});

// competition form edit
router.post('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', (req, res) => {
  var schoolName = req.body.schoolName;
  var competitionDate = req.body.competitionDate;
  var competitionTime = req.body.competitionTime;
  var competitionVenue = req.body.competitionVenue;
  var competitionTotalOfStudents = req.body.competitionTotalOfStudents;
  var competitionTotalParticipated = req.body.competitionTotalParticipated;
  var competitionTotalPersonnel = req.body.competitionTotalPersonnel;
  var competitionJudge1Name = req.body.competitionJudge1Name;
  var competitionJudge1Telephone = req.body.competitionJudge1Telephone;
  var competitionJudge1Email = req.body.competitionJudge1Email;
  var competitionJudge2Name = req.body.competitionJudge2Name;
  var competitionJudge2Telephone = req.body.competitionJudge2Telephone;
  var competitionJudge2Email = req.body.competitionJudge2Email;
  var competitionJudge3Name = req.body.competitionJudge3Name;
  var competitionJudge3Telephone = req.body.competitionJudge3Telephone;
  var competitionJudge3Email = req.body.competitionJudge3Email;

  // admin fields
  var competitionRequiredPhotos = req.body.competitionRequiredPhotos;
  var competitionRequiredCertifications = req.body.competitionRequiredCertification;
});
```

**What I'm expecting**

When the user signs in they should be able to fill in this form, the user belongs to this form, hence why it's based off the user id.

Not too sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Looks like you are not sending your user object to from your controller to your view

Comment: what do you get as response when post your form

Comment: See output on edit 1 @YouneL

Comment: Not sure how I can pass both the user and the form @KorayGocmen any help here would be amazing.

Comment: You are showing mongoose model output, if `req.params.id` represent a user id then you could pass it to the view: `res.render('dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Competition Form', user_id: req.params.id
    });`

Comment: When you say you can't post what exactly isn't happening? The document isn't being found/saved?

Comment: @YouneL See second update.

Comment: @RickyM See second update.

Comment: Next question, when you login does the client have the user id stored locally/in the session? Also, are you sure that the id parameter is the id for the logged in user? Note: It does not appear that you are saving the document at any point in the route.

Comment: If your question is does the `user.id` work, yes. Users are able to edit their accounts https://gyazo.com/a32f34c21d84d1cef7fa7aef8d464619 Users work as intended.

Comment: I just want that form to post and be unique to the user @RickyM

Comment: Please show the output of  `console.log(req.params.id);` in the post route handler

Comment: @YouneL The user is passing successfully https://gyazo.com/139cccd6be38823cc61badd09b1742fa I wouldn't be able to access the form otherwise.

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: `"mongoose": "^4.13.9",` @RickyM This is nothing to do with the version, more than the fact that the data of the form isn't saving and nothing is being passed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your view in order to use `user_id` passed by the route handler (i.e `router.get(...)`), also use [Model.findOneAndUpdate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate) to save posted data into database:

View:

```
<form action="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{ user_id }}" method="post">
```

Post handler:

```
router.post('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', (req, res) => {

    CompetitionForm.findOneAndUpdate( { _id: req.params.id }, req.body, (err, competition) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log(`Error saving data:  ${err}`);
            return res.send('Error saving data');
        }

        res.redirect('/dashboard');

    } );

});
```

Comment: Don't I need to pass in the form fields in to post request?

Comment: It depends to Competition schema, req.body should have the same structure to your schema if you want it to work, please try it and let me know if somethiing shows up to console

Comment: Ok so I tried this https://gyazo.com/8a916cc61ec415b9a643219ab779818e and I get the following output https://gyazo.com/70155860f218c7db950fd77b223fbb91

Comment: The same goes for this https://gyazo.com/7e31a95c6d59cf8781193de2cb403fb7 no errors are outputting and no updates in the db

Comment: https://gyazo.com/63f5bd844efe4b1348d776dfec19701f It's a bit small had to get everything in the screenshot. If you want me to paste in into the question above, let me know.

Comment: maybe `req.params.id` does not exist in database `competitionForms` collection ,  try to check if exists, also

Comment: How would I attach the user id to the form?

Comment: I updated my answer, use `{{ user_id }}` instead of `{{ user.id  }}` inside the form url

Comment: Ok so the id is being saved now but not any of the inputted data https://gyazo.com/d7b85f66ef6966966946a54e875d8420 so we're getting close I think :)

Comment: Maybe those data are already empty, try to console loge one of them to see if its empty

Comment: Yeah I get `undefined`, any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163513/discussion-between-younel-and-b-j-b).